# Why is my Tecno pop2 is unable to install YouTube?

Tags: google-play-store, youtube

I am trying to install YouTube. It directs me to Google Play store afterwards it shows app failed to install what can I do to install it?

Comment: What is the error message?post a screenshot of that? How much of free space is on your device? [edit] to add details, as also your device details and Android version

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Can you install other apps or this happens with any Store app?

If no apps install and you are 100% sure there is enough free space, you may have any of the endless **Google Play Store+Play Services** errors. Clearing app data for both and restarting the device usually fixes that. If not, stop and uninstall updates for both apps, restart the phone, leave it around 10 minutes idle to allow Play Services to update itself and the store app, then retry the installation.

Soon someone will appear suggesting to *manually downloading or updating Play Services or Play Store*; you are better off **ignoring** such idea. I've been using Android since 2.3 and I've had all kind of phones with all the Play Store problems you can possibly think of, manually updating services is a bad idea as long as the OS was not modified or messed up with in any way.